# Error while using get request in AngilarJS

Tags: angularjs

I have some JSON data in stored in file: `weeklyData.json` (which is inside folder *json*) that I want to display in console using GET request, but I'm getting result **undefined**.

My app.js file consist both approaches for GET request but the result remains same: **undefined**.

#### HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Crazy Data Component</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src=""></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

#### app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.msg = "Something";
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'json/weeklyData.json',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error.data)
    })
})

//    $http.get('json/weeklyData.json').success(function (data) {
//        $scope.dub = data;
//        console.log('$scope.dub', $scope.dub);
//    })
//})
```

Can someone suggest something?

Comment: can you open the json file in your browser ? might be the path ?

Comment: can you add a different message in the error callback?, right now you cannot know if the ajax request has been successful or not.

Comment: Are you using a web server to serve your page or have you loaded the page from the file system? Browsers will block xmlHttpRequest to file system.

Comment: @Dinosan0908 Yes, I can open it.

Comment: @richardtz What message should I add?

Comment: @GaryOtt I'm using file system.

Comment: @Adarsh, that is your problem then. You need to set up a web server like apache, nginx or any other to serve your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.. check below snippet,

Your sample json is not accessed. check your url .

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.msg = "Something";
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error.data)
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Crazy Data Component</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap_Plugin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src=""></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to work here.. but not in my case. Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: is your json folder in the same folder as app.js ?

Comment: then have to give the correct path.

eg: ../json/weeklyData.json (navigate once)

Comment: Your Json folder needs to be in the _Context path_ OR you need to give its exact location (e.g: D:\MyProject\Json\weeklyData.json). Its recommended to put project related files in the context path itself.